# ADO Parameter Error in VBScript

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, ado

I have tried many, many things, but keep getting error 3001 (Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another) when trying to add parameters to a command object.

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "ProcName"                
cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc

MsgBox("0")
'cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@InvoiceNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, sInvoice))
Set pInvoiceNumber = cmd.CreateParameter("@InvoiceNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, sInvoice)
cmd.Parameters.Append(pInvoiceNumber)
```

The connection object is valid and open at the time that this code runs.  The @InvoiceNumber parameter of the stored procedure is a varchar(100).  What am I missing here?

Comment: More specifically, the error occurs on the `Set pInvoiceNumber = ...` line.

Comment: `Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con`?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional yes.  As I mentioned, it is a valid and open connection object that that point.  Is that not the correct way to do it?

Comment: What I meant was, the issue might be the fact that you have not used `Set`.

Comment: Well perhaps you could get around explicitly defining parameters by using `Refresh()`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185125 ?

Comment: Can you show where `sInvoice` gets assigned or output its value prior to assigning it to the ADO parameter?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional ah, yes, I can try that.  And will try the answer below.  Bond: it is passed in, though I also tried hardcoding and it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to replicate the issue, but I'm working in Classic ASP. I found this post which sounds like it may be relevant though.

[VBA: Run-time error 3001 Arguments Are Of The Wrong Type... when setting ADODB.Command object members](http://keencode.blogspot.com/2014/01/vba-run-time-error-3001-arguments-are.html)

It seems the adVarChar and adParamInput constants may be the problem due to late binding.  The resolution was to add the constants to the Sub header.

If that's not feasible, try using Oracle Certified Professional's suggestion of Refresh

```vb
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "ProcName"                
cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters(0).Value  = sInvoice
```

Comment: The solution from your link is what did it.  Though I also used the "Set cmd.ActiveConnection" as suggested by @oraclecertifiedprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with include library ADOLib.inc on top of the asp.page